# How to resolve update trouble with counter component in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a React.js project and I'm trying to implement a simple counter component. However, I'm encountering an issue where the counter doesn't update properly when I click the buttons. What might be causing this problem?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleIncrement = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  const handleDecrement = () => {
    setCount(count - 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Counter App</h2>
      <p>Current Count: {count}</p>
      <button onClick={handleIncrement}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={handleDecrement}>Decrement</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Counter;
```

Despite clicking the "Increment" and "Decrement" buttons, the counter doesn't seem to update as expected. What's going wrong and how to fix this issue?

Comment: setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);